# PDF downloads unsuccessful on Samsung devices

Tags: android, html, pdf, download, samsung-mobile

I've set up a PDF link on a site

`<a href="/assets/img/Vitamin D Mission – HCP Fact sheet.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>`

this works fine on desktop; opens in a new tab and iPhone/Android devices download the pdf, however, on samsung devices: S3, S4 and Ace there's an error - it can't download succesfully

Any idea if this is a Samsung specific bug? any solutions?

Is it potentially due to the spaces within the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download it by renaming pdf name. Without space and special characters. It could be potentially risky file with them.